# Invoke C++ method from webviews Javascript

Tags: webview, qml, qtwebkit, qt5

In qt4 qml the qtwebkit 1.0 the component webview has a property `javaScriptWindowObjects`. I used it to add javaScriptWindowObjects to the context of my webpages javascript to call c++ functions. like so

```
WebView{
    url: "http://test.com"
    anchors.fill: parent
    scale: 1.0

    javaScriptWindowObjects: QtObject {
        WebView.windowObjectName: "native"

        function foo(x, y) {
             console.log("This is a call from javascript");
             myCppHandler.fooNative(b,c);
         }
    }
}
```

so i can call it from the webpages javascript like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    native.foo(1,2)
</script>
```

but in qt5 qml qtwebkit 3.0 there is no such thing like `javaScriptWindowObjects`

how can i achieve that in qt5 qml?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for the record to get this done:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtWebKit 3.0
import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0

Rectangle {

   width: 1024
   height: 768

   WebView{
       url: "http://localhost"
       anchors.fill: parent

       experimental.preferences.navigatorQtObjectEnabled: true
       experimental.onMessageReceived: {

           console.debug("get msg from javascript")
           experimental.postMessage("HELLO")
       }
   } // webview
} // rectanlge


<html>
<body>
<h1>It just works!</h1>

<p>Play with me...</p>

<button onclick="nativecall();">test</button>
<div id="out"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function nativecall(){
        console.log("will try native call");
        var elem = document.getElementById("out").innerHTML="clicked";
        navigator.qt.postMessage('this is a js call');
    }

    function jsCall(message){
        var elem = document.getElementById("out").innerHTML="and the other way around " + message;
    }

    navigator.qt.onmessage = function(ev) {
        jsCall(ev.data);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is fascinating, but I found that when turning on Experimental mode, even though I got the extra functionality, some odd things happened to the page controls. The checkboxes and radio buttons got wonky, the scrollbars disappeared (if I turned them on with DIVs), and the SELECT element stopped working. It's definitely a tech preview only in Qt 5.5 -- not ready for primetime.

Comment: @Volomike i didn't invest much time for qml recently and especially in this topic since the release of this application was back in march 2013. I am wondering you consider this a preview. at the time of writing it was. Today i would guess there is a stronger Implementation out there not prefixed "experimental". Unfortunately i've no time as of right now to investigate this further, but this answer seems to be outdated and needs "refactoring" anyway.

Comment: Qt 5.6 is beta as of 2015 Nov 20, but they do include QtWebView (not to be confused with QWebView) in it with the tech preview of Minibrowser as well. I haven't tried Qt 5.6 beta yet. Meanwhile, there's a lively discussion going on with developers upset about the web component direction in Qt after 5.5 here: http://forum.qt.io/topic/55504/anyone-knows-the-future-of-qt-webkit

Comment: @Volomike Thx i'll probably read it in its entirety when i got home from work ... the first few post are not that encouraging :/ i thought after nearly 3 years webkit was fully replaced by webengine that sounds awfully sad :(

Comment: There are other options, perhaps, if needing this for OSX or iOS. For instance, MacGap1 (available on Github), and perhaps a way to glue that to Qt/C++ (or Qt/whatever language). Or, do the work in native XCode against the webkit library there, and then have it call your Qt dynlibs.

Comment: Can this be done with new `WebEngineView`? I tried but failed with `Cannot assign to non-existent property "preferences"`. I'm using Qt 5.7.0 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Qt 5.8.0 QML & JavaScript binding

QML code

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtWebEngine 1.4
import QtWebChannel  1.0

Item{
    id:root
    height: 500
    width:  500

// Create WebChannel
WebChannel{
    id:webChannel
}

//Now, let’s create an object that we want to publish to the HTML/JavaScript clients:
QtObject {
    id: myObject
    objectName: "myObject"

    // the identifier under which this object
    // will be known on the JavaScript side
    //WebChannel.id: "webChannel"

    property var send: function (arg) {
                sendTextMessage(arg);
            }

    // signals, methods and properties are
    // accessible to JavaScript code
    signal someSignal(string message);


    function someMethod(message) {
        console.log(message);
        someSignal(message);
        return dataManager.getGeoLat();
    }

    property string hello: "world";
}

Rectangle{
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "black"

WebEngineView{
    id : webEnginView
    anchors.fill: parent
    url : dataManager.htmlURL();
    webChannel: webChannel
}
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    webChannel.registerObject("foo", myObject);
}
}
```

HTML Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="qrc:/Map/qwebchannel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel) {
    // all published objects are available in channel.objects under
    // the identifier set in their attached WebChannel.id property
    var foo = channel.objects.foo;

    // access a property
    alert(foo.hello);

    // connect to a signal
    foo.someSignal.connect(function(message) {
        alert("Got signal: " + message);
    });

    // invoke a method, and receive the return value asynchronously
       foo.someMethod("bar", function(ret) {
       alert("Got return value: " + ret);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: But what about **WebView** (OP asked about this one)?